# Enable switch perspective in developer console

Tags: developer-console

How to enable switch perspective in developer console . switch perspective is greyed out and hence log is not getting displayed in console.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, I think I know the answer to this one, since I just came across it myself. The Switch Perspective menu is not enabled until you open a Log.

So click the Logs tab, then open a Log, when it is open, then you can choose Debug > Switch Perspective.